# VS View memory window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

When my c# application breaks the Debug + Window menu does not show an entry for Memory window. The menu has items for Breakpoints,threads,locals, watch  and callstack. How can I enable memory window. I use VS2005 and VS2008. Both has the problem

Answer (score 3):

This is a view that can be accessed from the Debug option in the Menu bar.  It is under views, I believe.  The keystroke is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd> (key chord, release first 3 keys before pressing <kbd>1</kbd>).  You can see more keystokes [here](http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The memory window is [not available in Visual Studio 2005/2008 Express Edition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d2www5s(v=vs.90).aspx). You need a Standard or Professional license.

The [Visual Studio 2015 page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e.aspx) makes no mention of any limitations related to which edition you're running, so I suspect VS 2015 Community Edition has this window.